# Delphi - Indy close all the forms that related to client

Tags: forms, delphi, indy

I'm trying to close all the forms that related to client once he disconnected form the server

This action will be on the server side.

I have ( the known for me at run time ) partial unique caption for each client for example

Form caption 1:

```
ServiceA - ClientABC
```

Form caption 2:

```
ServiceB - ClientABC
```

What i already know is the `- ClientABC` part only.

So when the client `ClientABC` disconnected form my server i want to close all the related opened form in the server side.

```
procedure TIdServer.ClientRemove(const AContext: TIdContext);
var
   sTitle: string;
  function CloseChildForm(Wnd: HWND; Param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
  begin
       if Pos(sTitle, _GetWindowTitle(Wnd)) <> 0 then
          PostMessage(Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
       Result := True;
  end;
begin
     sTitle := TMyContext(AContext).Uniquename {ClientABC}
     if Assigned(FListView) then begin
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          var
            i: Integer;
          begin
               EnumWindows(@CloseChildForm, 0);

               .......

               end;

          end
        );
     end;
end;
```

My problem is the string `sTitle` inside the `CloseChildForm` function always empty.

I call `ClientRemove` on the `IdServerDisconnect` procedure

```
procedure TIdServer.IdServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
     TMyContext(AContext).Queue.Clear;
     ........
     ClientRemove(AContext);
end;
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong please ?

Comment: Why not just give `TMyContext` its own list of associated windows? When a window is opened, add it to the client's list. When a window is closed, remove it from the client's list. When a client disconnects, loop through its list closing any windows that are still open. You should be **keeping track** of your windows, not **hunting** for them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong here:

- You must not use a nested function as your callback. That is not allowed by the language and your code only compiles because the RTL declaration of `EnumWindows` uses an untyped pointer for the callback parameter.
- Asynchronous execution with `TThread.Queue` means that the enclosing stack frame can be finished before the call to `EnumWindows` completes.
- You are in danger of closing windows that do not belong in your process.

Were I faced with this problem I would solve it using `Screen.Forms[]`. Something like this:

```
for i := Screen.FormCount-1 downto 0 do
  if CaptionMatches(Screen.Forms[i]) then
    Screen.Forms[i].Close;
```

This is just an outline. I'm sure you can understand the concept. The key point is not to use `EnumWindows` and instead use the VCL's own mechanism to enumerate your forms.